# Deep key structure based on recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion, lodash

I've been using lodash for a while now and I really love the `_.set` and `_.get` methods.

I'm trying to solve a problem to get the deep key paths whose final value is a string, but when I'm too dumb for it. Spend 3 hours on it and can't find a perfect solution:

```
const myObject = {
  a: 'myObject.a',
  b: {
    ba: 'myObject.b.ba',
    bb: ['myObject.b.bb[0]'],
  },
  c: [
    { ca: 'myObject.c[0].ca' },
  ],
};
```

So I have `myObject` (that's far more nested in real life) and I want to get paths to the values, but only the final one.

The method would look like `getDeepPaths(myObject)` and would return in this case: `['myObject.a', 'myObject.b.ba', 'myObject.b.bb[0]', 'myObject.c[0].ca' ]`

Did anyone solve something like this before?

Comment: I have solved something similar but have to dig it and I'm getting late right now. But hints: You will have to use recursion. Instead of `.a` try `['a']`. Its simpler to write an algo for a common pattern.

Comment: Thanks @Rajesh for your response and for the hint. I will try it as soon as I have a walk. A recursion is something that make my head feel like it's going to explode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursion is actually not that hard. Here's how you could solve this problem:

```js
const myObject = {
  a: 'myObject.a',
  b: {
    ba: 'myObject.b.ba',
    bb: ['myObject.b.bb[0]'],
  },
  c: [
    { ca: 'myObject.c[0].ca' },
  ],
};


var stringLeaves = function(path, obj) {

  if (typeof obj === 'string') {
    return [path]
  }

  return Object.keys(obj)
          .filter(k => obj.hasOwnProperty(k))
          .map(k => stringLeaves(path + '.' + k, obj[k]))
          .reduce((a,x) => a.concat(x), []); // this line flattens the array
};

console.log(stringLeaves('myObject', myObject));
```

The work is done by the `stringLeaves` function. In this function:

- if the `obj` passed in as a parameter is a string, then just return the current path.
- otherwise we assume that the object is an array, or a generic object, in which case we iterate through its properties:

  - for each property, call `stringLeaves` recursively, by passing in the adjusted path (current path + the new property name) and the object/value that resides at that particular key.

The convention of the function is that it returns an array of all possible matches. This is why:

- for scalar string values I return an array (to keep things consistent)
- I have the `.reduce((a,x) => a.concat(x), []);` line: to transform an array of arrays into one array that consists of all the values present in the original arrays.

Note that the function cannot deduce that your object is called `myObject`, so I passed that name as an initial path.

Comment: That works really great. I've managed to came up with my own solution, but it's just less elegant version of what you have wrote. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I'll provide a more generic solution that doesn't use lodash or other external dependencies

```
const traverse = function* (node, path = [])
{
  if (Object (node) === node)
    for (const [ key, value ] of Object.entries (node))
      yield* traverse (value, [ ...path, key ])
  else
    yield [ path, node ]
}
```

We can easily step thru our data using a `for` loop. Notice the generator yields a `path`-`value` pair for each value in the original object. *All* primitive values are included in the output, not just strings this time

```
// add a non-string value for demo
const myObject = {
  ...
  d: 1
};

for (const [ path, value ] of traverse (myObject)) {
  console.log ('path', path)
  console.log ('value', value)
  console.log ('---')
}

// path [ 'a' ]
// value myObject.a
// ---
// path [ 'b', 'ba' ]
// value myObject.b.ba
// ---
// path [ 'b', 'bb', '0' ]
// value myObject.b.bb[0]
// ---
// path [ 'c', '0', 'ca' ]
// value myObject.c[0].ca
// ---
// path [ 'd' ]
// value 1
// ---
```

If we wanted to, we can collect all of the pairs using `Array.from`

```
Array.from (traverse (myObject))
// [ [ [ 'a' ], 'myObject.a' ]
// , [ [ 'b', 'ba' ], 'myObject.b.ba' ]
// , [ [ 'b', 'bb', '0' ], 'myObject.b.bb[0]' ]
// , [ [ 'c', '0', 'ca' ], 'myObject.c[0].ca' ]
// , [ [ 'd' ], 1 ]
// ]
```

As you may have noticed, I keep `path` as an array rather than making it a `.`-separated string. There's no need to make it into a string just to split it apart again later.

```
const lookup = (obj, [ key, ...path ]) =>
  obj && key
    ? lookup (obj [key], path)
    : obj

for (const [ path, value ] of traverse (myObject)) {
  console.log ('path', path)
  console.log ('value', value)
  console.log ('lookup', lookup (myObject, path))
  console.log ('---')
}

// path [ 'a' ]
// value myObject.a
// lookup myObject.a
// ---
// path [ 'b', 'ba' ]
// value myObject.b.ba
// lookup myObject.b.ba
// ---
// path [ 'b', 'bb', '0' ]
// value myObject.b.bb[0]
// lookup myObject.b.bb[0]
// ---
// path [ 'c', '0', 'ca' ]
// value myObject.c[0].ca
// lookup myObject.c[0].ca
// ---
// path [ 'd' ]
// value 1
// lookup 1
// ---
```